# How to add loader over canvas element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas

I have a canvas element that loads the Babylon model. I'm having trouble while adding a loader to the canvas element.

HTML code for canvas:

```
<canvas id='canvas' width={120} height={120} ></canvas>
```

This canvas element is inside `<div>`. I want to add a loader instead of canvas until the canvas fully loads, once it's done loading show the model in canvas and stop the loader.

Code for showing model in canvas using Babylon is already done, what's left is adding loader to the canvas.

Also, I have to do this without changing the HTML code or by adding an id to div.

I can't show the whole code but these are the first 2 lines of the script after this, it starts loading the model in canvas.

Loading Canvas Code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true);
........
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a loader using javascript createElement at the start of the function and later display: none the div when at the end of the function.

eg you could do something like this:

```
var ctx = document.createElement('div');
var ctxPar = document.createElement('div');
ctxPar.setAttribute('id', 'parentModelLoaderdiv');
ctx.setAttribute('id', 'modelLoader');
ctxPar.append(ctx);
canvas.after(ctxPar);
console.log(ctx);
document.getElementById(option).style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('modelLoader').style.display = 'block';
```

Now at the end of the function when the canvas is ready to display do:

```
document.getElementById(canvasClass).style.display = 'inline-block';
document.getElementById('parentModelLoaderdiv').remove();
```